# Async .map() not working within React hook

Tags: reactjs

I cannot understand why the `.map()` function is somehow not being called in this function.  I'm trying to call my API asynchronously within the `componentDidMount()` hook, but it seems that the array method never gets called.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(`Returned: ${data.zipCodes.length} results`);
    console.log(data.zipCodes[0]);
    const geoPoints = data.zipCodes;
    geoPoints
      .filter(geoPoint => geoPoint.Recipient_Postal_Code !== "")
      .map(function (geoPoint) {
        const location = zipToLocation.find(element => element.fields.zip === geoPoint.Recipient_Postal_Code);
        if (!location){
          return;
        }
        if(!location.hasOwnProperty('fields')) {
          return;
        }
        const lat = location.fields.latitude;
        const lng = location.fields.longitude;
        const result = {
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng,
          trackingNumber: geoPoint.Shipment_Tracking_Number
        }
        console.log(result); //OK!
        return result;
      });
    console.log(`Mapped ${geoPoints.length} geoPoints`);
    console.log(geoPoints);  //same data as data.zipCodes ??
    this.setState({data: geoPoints}) 
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Is is somehow being disrupted by React?

Comment: Try removing aync from the definition. It shouldn't be an sync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map` doesn't edit the input array, it returns a new array that is created from the old one.

You want to put:

```
const geoPoints = data.zipCodes
                      .filter(...)
                      .map(...);
```